# Unable to set Destination Endpoint through OpsHub TF31003

Tags: visual-studio-2012, opshub

I am trying to migrate from TFS2010 to Visual Studio Team Services using OpsHub.

**Problem:**
When I try to set the Destination Endpoint from within OpsHub it brings ups "Connect to Team Project Collection". From here I have to "Add Team Foundation Server". I enter https://[~mysitename~].visualstudio.com. At this point I don't get the opportunity to enter user/password (which I do when going through the same process with VS2015). It tries to connect and returns the Error ..

> TF31003: Either you have not entered the necessary credentials or your
>   user account does not have permission to connect to the Team
>   Foundation Server at ..."

My suspicion is that it is using the VS2012 instance to connect and not the VS2015 instance. Is there any way to change this or is there some other way to pass in my user/pass and connect.

**Background:**
I have Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 installed on my machine.

I have created a new Account under Visual Studio Online and have added a team project.

I can successfully connect to the team project from VS 2015 under Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with credential caching in IE.

Please try to clear your IE cache, stored creds/cookies etc after closing any open Visual Studio instances and the OVSMU tool.

Also clear out your local TFS/VS cache by the following steps:

Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents of the below folders

1)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

2)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

3)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache
{the folders would exists, based on the version of Visual Studio installed.}

On restart, try to add the end point again, this time it should show the pop-up required for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to [migrate TFS to VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts), and you can also download the migration guide [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/?utm_source=ms&utm_medium=guide&utm_campaign=vstsdataimportguide).